# What does this asm code mean & how can I inspect those values?

Tags: assembly, gdb

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000100000de6 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000100000de7 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000100000dea <main+4>:    sub    $0x30,%rsp
0x0000000100000dee <main+8>:    mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
0x0000000100000df1 <main+11>:   mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
0x0000000100000df5 <main+15>:   movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
0x0000000100000dfd <main+23>:   cmpl   $0x2,-0x14(%rbp)
```

I want to understand 3rd line.

$0x30 ?(constant 0x30? or the value of address 0x30 ? , if then, how can I access that value? if I type 'p *0x30', an error occurs. (Can this change the stack pointer's value?? <-- target is rsp? not '$0x30'?)

And

What is -0x14(%rbp) ??

(I use OSX)
Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 4):

The first two instructions are setting up a *stack frame*.
Then in order of appearance:

```
<main+0>:    push   %rbp
<main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
<main+4>:    sub    $0x30,%rsp       ;reserves 48 bytes on the stack for local variables
<main+8>:    mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp) ;stores %edi at the address that is less than %rbp by 20 bytes 
<main+11>:   mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp) ; stores %rdi at the address that is less than %rbp by 32 bytes
<main+15>:   movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp) ; clears the qword at -0x8(%rbp)
```

Comment: Thank you Serge! I have an additional question. These instructions take their target as a second argument, but I knew that the order must be reversed in Intel architecture. Have I been wrong??

Comment: gcc uses AT&T notation to print assembly listings as well as generate files that you may assemble. By the AT&T notation the source operand is at the left and the destination operand at the right.

Answer (score 0):

`$0x30` is the constant hexadecimal value 30 (48 in decimal). What that line does is it subtracts 48 from `%esp`, the stack pointer - effectively pushing 48 bytes to the stack (remember, the stack grows downwards).

`-0x14(%rbp)` is the value at address `%rbp - 0x14` - in C terminology, it is roughly

```
unisigned char *rbp; // this is the rbp register
unsidned long edi;
edi = *(unsigned long *)(rbp - 0x14) // this is the actual value.
```

Note the cast to word size - CPU registers usually hold a word worth of data.